# Confirm dialog before action call on Struts 1

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts-1

On my Struts 1 project I have a form with a submit button that redirects to a Java action class, but now I need a confirm dialog (eventually customizable) that asks for a confirm.

How can I do this on Struts/JSP?

```
<html:form action="/Login">
    <html:hidden property="saveCheck" />
        User Name : <html:text name="LoginForm" property="userName" />
    <br>
        Password  : <html:password name="LoginForm"
        property="password" />
    <br>
    <html:submit property="method" value="Login"/>
</html:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is you can use the `onclick` event to make a confirm before you submit:

```
<html:submit property="method" value="Login" onclick="javascript:return confirm('are you sure?');"/>
```

Similar action when you use a custom dialog.

If the solution is not meet your require, please give us more detail.